# recv function for winsock socket

Tags: windows, tcp, telnet, sockets

I have a server application which is connected with telnet client(i.e. telnet localhost _port_num - here port number is same associated with the server application),

My application works correctly, but the thing is I used recv as follows:

```
#define BUFLEN 512
char buf[BUFLEN];
iResult = recv(sd, (char *)buf, BUFLEN, 0);
```

here recv call returns as soon as any character pressed over the connected telnet terminal, and most of the time iResult is `1` or some times `2`, Even though I wouldn't press enter telnet client sends frame containing a single character to the server application.

How can I make sure that recv should return after BUFLEN read ?
In case of linux recv works as expected, get blocks until `enter`.

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: How can I make sure that ... BUFLEN read ?

A: You read in a loop until you get all the characters you expect.  Or until you get a timeout, or an error.

Comment: But I guess it's not a proper way, recv should block until enter key pressed in telnet terminal. If the number of bytes is more than it will read upto BUFLEN and raise appropriate error falg, and telnet will preserve the data which is not read and on next read I could read from where it's left... My part is why recv returns as soon as a single charater input on telnet

Comment: 'recv should block until enter key pressed in telnet terminal' - no.  No matter how much you wish for the documented behaviour of recv() to match your expectations, design and code, it's not gonna change.

Comment: Can you please explore your comment? Do you mean that even if we don't press enter over telnet terminal then also it will send the character. Is it contradicting with the telnet client in linux ?

Comment: Here I want to make note that, Using Putty telent client in windows gives the same behavior as in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call recv function again and again until your desired amount of data is received. Please note that when you use TCP Sockets, you cannot make sure if you receive all data in single receive call. If you send data using single TCP Send() call, then it is fairly possible that you receive it in multiple receives as TCP sockets are Stream Sockets.

The recv() function returns the number of bytes received, so you can keep calling the function until you get all they bytes.